# Citations do not show correctly in the \include{} text

Tags: citing, include, cite-package

I am writing my thesis, and I use `\include{}` command so I could write each chapter separately and then combine them in the main document to have a more clear structure.
However, I find that the citations in the chapter texts show [?]. Below is a simple example.

Here is the main document

```
\input{setup/preamble.tex}% package inclusion and set up of the document
\input{setup/hyphenations.tex}%
\input{setup/macros.tex}% my new macros

\begin{document}
%frontmatter
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty} %disable headers and footers
\pagenumbering{roman} %use roman page numbering in the frontmatter
\input{frontmatter/frontpage}
\input{frontmatter/colophon}
\input{frontmatter/cv}
\input{frontmatter/abstract}
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{label:contents}
\pagestyle{fancy} %enable headers and footers again
\tableofcontents
\listoftodos
\input{frontmatter/preface}
\cleardoublepage

%mainmatter
\mainmatter
\include{chapters/chapter1}
\include{chapters/chapter2}
\par Text in the main document \cite{reference5, reference6}.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran.bst}
\bibliography{references/mybib.bib}
\end{document}
```

Here is the "mybib.bib".

```
@article{reference1,
  title={Title of Reference1},
  author={Author 1},
  journal={Journal1},
  volume={x},
  pages={x},
  year={x},
  publisher={x}
}

@article{reference2,
    title={Title of Reference2},
    author={Author 2},
    journal={Journal2},
    volume={x},
    pages={x},
    year={x},
    publisher={x}
}

@article{reference3,
    title={Title of Reference3},
    author={Author 3},
    journal={Journal3},
    volume={x},
    pages={x},
    year={x},
    publisher={x}
}

@article{reference4,
    title={Title of Reference4},
    author={Author 4},
    journal={Journal4},
    volume={x},
    pages={x},
    year={x},
    publisher={x}
}

@article{reference5,
    title={Title of Reference5},
    author={Author 5},
    journal={Journal5},
    volume={x},
    pages={x},
    year={x},
    publisher={x}
}

@article{reference6,
    title={Title of Reference6},
    author={Author 6},
    journal={Journal6},
    volume={x},
    pages={x},
    year={x},
    publisher={x}
}
```

It can be seen that I write chapter1 and chapter2 in other files, and combined them in the main document using `\include{}`.

The text for chapter1 is `Text for Chapter 1 \cite{reference1, reference2}.` and the text for chapter2 is `Text for Chapter 2 \cite{reference3, reference4}.`. For comparison, I also add a short text directly in the main document `\par Text in the main document \cite{reference5, reference6}.`.

After compiling, the citations in chapter1 and chapter2 all show as "?"

[image]

and

[image]

And the TeXstudio says that the citations in the texts are undefined.
[image]

Only the citations in the text directly written in the main document show correctly.
[image]

However, all the referred documents appear correctly in the "References".
[image]

It seems that I have defined all the citations, but they could not be identified by the texts in `\include{}`?
Hence, could I consult how could I fix the citations in the chapters to make them show the correct number of referred documents?

Comment: what you show is expected until you run bibtex to generate the biblography and then run latex twice to reolve cross references

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number